# How do you get past the board with the fly in Limbo?

Tags: limbo

I can sneak up very close to the fly, but if I try to jump on him or get closer than where I am in the photo, he flies off.

[image]

Comment: What level is it? Or the name of the level?

Comment: I don't know if they have numbers. The game just sidescrolls.  The image should show where it is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This level is chapter 15 in Limbo.

You have to sneak up to the fly, and as it takes off jump and grabs its legs.
Here is a [demonstration on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bYXEO-ZbOQ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, nothing in the game so far as responded to speed rather than position so I didn't expect it to!

Comment: FYI, your video is broken.